# How/Where can I find vector data for building footprints in Texas?

Tags: vector, footprint

I've done a lot of research on this topic over the past 8 or 9 months, but I'm a GIS newb, so I may have overlooked some possibilities for finding/extracting this data.

A short list of resources I have researched (an exhaustive list would be very long):

1. Tax Net USA - Text data on properties is free. You have to pay to get footprint images. I don't mind paying, but their search interface is cumbersome, and the images they provide are small raster PNGs with 'cruft' that I don't need, such as dimensions. Additionally, each image is 'divorced' from the real world - there is no lat/lon or compass orientation information in the images. On the plus side, the images are detailed and are often accurate to within a foot or so.
2. ArcGIS - The Texas maps seem to have acceptable coverage and reasonably accurate building footprint polygons, but I have no idea how I would go from a street address to a vector graphic of the building(s) at the address using ArcGIS (or whether that's even feasible).
3. OpenStreetMap - Very sparse coverage of buildings in the central Texas area, the area I'm most interested in.

I'm not frightened by a highly technical solution. I'm a software developer, so I'm willing to install, write and/or interface with software to do the job.

Requirements in order of importance: Vector representation, accuracy, "queryability" (publicly available API would be great), lat/lon & compass orientation info.

I'm OK with querying each address individually, on an as-needed basis, but a bulk dataset would also be interesting.

Comment: Some places, [like Bexar County](http://bit.ly/zqeHLD) participate in Esri's [Community Basemap Program](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/community-maps-program/index.html).  Participants upload vectors, which Esri uses to generate tiles.  I've not seen any Esri mapservices for building footprint vectors, but it might be worth asking them.

Comment: Just as an update, The Brazoria County Appraisal District in Texas offers a free-to-download improvement footprint layer. We are now maintaining this layer and each month we will offer a more up to date layer. http://www.brazoriacad.org/tax-roll--gis-downloads.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I wanted some ready-to-go building footprints, I'd start calling **county Assessor offices** and **city planning departments**. I think they will be your best bet for ready-made building footprint polygons. However because these are expensive data, I believe it's rare to find them free for the taking. It's likely even rarer to find it associated with sparsely-populated areas. :/

On the other hand, if you can get LIDAR data for your area of interest, you could use [Whitebox GAT](https://jblindsay.github.io/ghrg/Whitebox/) to perform building footprint extraction. I just followed [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120617013857/http://www.uoguelph.ca:80/%7Ehydrogeo/Whitebox/Tutorials/Tutorial_2_DEMs_and_TA.pdf), which comes with some sample data. I uploaded a couple screenshots for you.

The first image is the "first return" values from the LIDAR data, I identified some areas to consider marked with black squares:

[image]

This next image is the building extraction (buildings in red).  The area at the top seems unlike the obvious buildings. I suspect it's a pond. Also, that curvilinear stretch is unexpected, maybe I did something wrong configuring the method arguments..

[image]

Unfortunately, the sample data didn't include an aerial to compare to the LIDAR data, so it's difficult to be very confident with the extractions. I grabbed some "actual" LIDAR data ([Jasper County, MO](https://www.msdis.missouri.edu/data/lidar/index.html)) from another source, and that dataset wasn't as plug-and-play, leading me to believe some post-processing/cleaning is necessary in order to get the same caliber of feature extraction I enjoyed with the sample data.

Anyway, assuming you perfected the processing/extraction methodology, you could then take footprint the rasters extracted from Whitebox and run them through [gdal_polygonize](https://gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) to create a building footprint polygon layer.

On another note, and regarding this statement..

> ..I have no idea how I would go from a street address to a vector graphic of the buildings..

Assuming the vector graphics you mention are *spatially aware* (that is ArcGIS or [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) load it in the correct position relative to other datasets), you should be able to [geocode your street addresses](https://web.archive.org/web/20150627131505/http://www.gsd.harvard.edu:80/gis/manual/geocoding/index.htm) as a stand-alone point layer. Then, once you have geocoded street points, you could implement that layer "invisibly" as a foundation for footprint queries.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll leave the question marked 'unanswered' a bit longer to see whether anyone else has additional tips.

Comment: NP, I can appreciate that this isn't a favorable solution. If you want to keep attention on your question, I recommend returning periodically to make minor edits/updates to the original question. Doing this will keep it active, and therefore closer to the top of the various lists. Once the question activity (it's presently at 8 days) drops enough to fall off the first page of hits, you'll get fewer and fewer views, and the odds of a preferable answer only get worse. I wonder if my making a comment here will renew its active status?

Comment: Unfortunately comments must not be enough to renew the thread's active status. A new answer might.. but editing/updating your question definitely will.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a program called Spatial Analysist that will does a good job of extracting building footprint polygons from imagry, not just Lidar. It works as a plugin to ArcGis.

Comment: Pretty sure it's *not* called Spatial Analyst. Were you thinking of [Overwatch Feature Analyst](http://www.featureanalyst.com/feature_analyst.htm)?

Comment: You may be referring to the [Image Analysis](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/products/erdasextensionsforarcgis/imageanalysisforarcgis/Details.aspx) extension for ArcGIS

Comment: @Nathan Do you mean ArcGIS `Spatial Analyst Tools`?